# Putty Always Locks Up on Disconnect in Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: windows-7, putty

I just got a new computer with Windows 7 (64 bit), installed the latest version of Putty, and find that Putty always locks up once I disconnect an SSH session or when I get disconnected (e.g. when the server reboots).

Putty works great until that point and hangs every time on disconnect.

The only way I found to terminate Putty at that point is to kill it through the task list.

Anyone else seeing that?  Any known fix?

Comment: Putty for me hangs when exiting in Windows XP on some computers for me. Are you by any chance running Macafee?

Comment: We're running ESET Smart Security 4.

Comment: What version did you download? I ask because I have this EXACT SAME ISSUE. And the strange thing is, on my HP HDX18T notebook where I have this problem, I am running the x64 version v0.60. I am running the exact same version on my desktop computer, and it doesn't lock up there. This leads me to believe there is a little something more to this than just version. There is something hardware related here that is impacting this. Both setups run Win 7 Ultimate, x64, 8GB RAM.

Comment: I dont know about hardware being a cause, but there's something going on. On my main computer, Win7 x64, it works fine... On my new laptop, HP Elitebook 8440p running Win7 x64, it doesnt. And yes, this is the latest 0.60...a very annoying problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the latest Putty build and this problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I haven't quite figured out how I can answer my last post (Nov 21 at 12:05). Anyway, I have put putty in xp-mode now and I haven't had a problem since and this is almost 3 weeks ago.

If I remember correctly you have to put the putty connection manager into xp-mode aswell in order to be able to use them with each other. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

See if forks like [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.com/) exhibit the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is an X64 build of Putty for AMD64 architectures at http://www.kelley.ca/amd64/

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was right-click on Putty, Properties, Compatibility Tab, Run As Administrator. I can deal with the single Cancel or Allow popup & it works even better when you switch Putty to "Close window on exit: Never".

Comment: Responding to Eric J's answer: for me the latest build solved the problem when I closed the connection, but whenever the server disconnected (timeout, etc), it still locked up, until I switched to runing putty as admin. I have Windows 7 64-bit on an HP dv6tse.